# How to select values from one table with a condition based on the second table?

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables: `USERS` (which has an unique_id +more) and `MESSAGES` (incoming_user_id and outcoming_user_id +more). I want to display all the users that have been sending messages with the unique_id, only those users!!
I have tried this, but is still displaying all the users (even users with who our unique_id has no message sent):

```
$sql = "SELECT users.* 
        FROM users, messages 
        WHERE messages.outgoing_user_id = users.unique_id 
        OR messages.incoming_user_id = users.unique_id GROUP BY unique_id ";
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are two different database management systems, please tag the actual DBMS you're using. Also provide a [mre].

Comment: For example I have the following users' unique_ids: 1,2,3,4,5,6. And in messages table I have: Msg_id = 1 : incoming_user_id = 2; outgoing_user_id = 4;                                               Msg_id = 2 : incoming_user_id = 2; outgoing_user_id = 1;                                                             Msg_id = 3 : incoming_user_id = 4; outgoing_user_id = 2;                                                        Msg_id = 4 : incoming_user_id = 4; outgoing_user_id = 3;    So for unique_id = 4, I want to display users 2 and 3, because they are the ones who talked to user no. 4

Comment: Sample data is a good idea. But please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69736784/edit) your request and add the sample data along with the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest joining the two tables (probably on the user id property) and then SELECT the messages WHERE your condition applies

Comment: but I have two cases: if the user is an incoming or outgoing user.. so how would look like that join? And also, I want to return the matching users, not messages..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lookup rows in a table use `EXISTS` or `IN`. One simple query:

```
select * 
from users
where unique_id in 
(
  select outgoing_user_id
  from messages
  where incoming_user_id = 4
)
or unique_id in 
(
  select incoming_user_id
  from messages
  where outgoing_user_id = 4
);
```

The same thing slighty shorter:

```
select * 
from users
where unique_id in 
(
  select case when outgoing_user_id = 4 then incoming_user_id
                                        else outgoing_user_id end
  from messages
  where incoming_user_id = 4 or outgoing_user_id = 4
);
```

Or with `EXISTS`:

```
select * 
from users u
where unique_id <> 4
and exists
(
  select null
  from messages m
  where u.unique_id in (m.incoming_user_id, m.outgoing_user_id)
    and 4           in (m.incoming_user_id, m.outgoing_user_id)
);
```